# AutoFixture 2 With() isn't working as it did in AutoFixture 1?

Tags: autofixture

I'm porting my tests to [AutoFixture 2.0](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/), and I've run in to some strange behavior that I can neither explain nor fix.  This simple test is failing for me:

```
var autoFixtures = new Fixture();
var file = autoFixtures.Build<File>()
                       .With(f => f.Name, "bleh.txt")
                       .CreateAnonymous();

Assert.That(file.Name, Is.EqualTo("bleh.txt"));  // Fail?!
```

The test succeeds if I change `Name` to another property of `File`, which leads me to think that I have some sort of customization present for `Name` that wasn't working when I was using AutoFixture 1.0.  I've scoured my code, though, and I can't find anything like that.

Enabling tracing doesn't seem to help much.

```
autoFixtures.Behaviors.Add(new TracingBehavior());
```

displays, among other stuff:

```
Requested: System.String Name
    Requested: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
    Created: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.NoSpecimen
  Requested: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
    Requested: System.String
    Created: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.NoSpecimen
    Requested: System.String
    Created: 8a022fda-fa4e-49b7-b0c2-285fef765386
  Created: Name8a022fda-fa4e-49b7-b0c2-285fef765386
Created: Name8a022fda-fa4e-49b7-b0c2-285fef765386
```

FWIW, `Name` is declared as a virtual property of `File`'s base class, and then overridden in `File` as such:

```
public abstract class Item
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class File : Item
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

If anyone has any ideas on something I might try, or somewhere I might have inadvertently customized the behavior of the `Name` property, I would be most appreciative!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just found a bug in AutoFixture 2.0. I have now resolved it and pushed the changes to the repository (changeset 3efe812aecd1), so if you [download the latest source](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) and compile it, it should work.

In case you are interested, it was related to a virtual property being overridden by a child class - apparently not something I do very often.

Sorry about the bug. Please let me know if the issue hasn't been resolved, or if you have other questions.

Comment: Ouch!  That makes me feel better about spending a bunch of time on it now, at least.  Glad it's all fixed up!