# Can AutoFixture execute a delegate at object creation time?

Tags: c#, autofixture

I'm looking to customize the creation-time behavior of [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) such that I can set up some dependent objects after the properties of the fixture have been generated and assigned.

For example, suppose I have a method that customizes a `User` because its `IsDeleted` property always has to be false for a certain set of tests:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public static ObjectBuilder<User> BuildUser(this Fixture f)
{
   return f.Build<User>().With(u => u.IsDeleted, false);
}
```

(I hand an `ObjectBuilder` back to the test so it can further customize the fixture if necessary.)

What I'd like to do is automatically associate that user with an anonymous collection by its `Id` at creation time, but I can't do this as-is because `Id` has not been generated by the time I hand the return value back to the unit test proper.  Here's the sort of thing I'm trying to do:

```
public static ObjectBuilder<User> BuildUserIn(this Fixture f, UserCollection uc)
{
   return f.Build<User>()
           .With(u => u.IsDeleted, false);
           .AfterCreation(u =>
            {
               var relation = f.Build<UserCollectionMembership>()
                               .With(ucm => ucm.UserCollectionId, uc.Id)
                               .With(ucm => ucm.UserId, u.Id)
                               .CreateAnonymous();
               Repository.Install(relation);
            }
}
```

Is something like this possible?  Or perhaps there is a better way to accomplish my goal of creating an anonymous object graph?

Comment: Do you want to have a specific instance for the User type and reuse it's Id property value somewhere else?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398258/customizing-autofixture-builder-with-seeded-property/5398653#5398653

Comment: @MarkSeemann: `Do()` can apparently execute before the object is fully populated, so that doesn't work.  I can (and do) manually execute the example lambda or do my object customization post-creation, but I'd love an alternative similar to the above!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `Build` method, this isn't possible, and probably never will be, because there are much better options available.

First of all, it should never be necessary to write static helper methods around the `Build` method. The `Build` method is for truly one-off initializations where one needs to define property or field values before the fact.

I.e. imagine a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string txt;

    public string SomeWeirdText
    {
        get { return this.txt; }
        set
        {
            if (value != "bar")
                throw new ArgumentException();
            this.txt = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In this (contrived) example, a straight `fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyClass>` is going to throw because it's going to attempt to assign something other than "bar" to the property.

In a one-off scenario, one can use the `Build` method to escape this problem. One example is simply to set the value explicitly to "bar":

```
var mc =
    fixture.Build<MyClass>().With(x => x.SomeWeirdText, "bar").CreateAnonymous();
```

However, even easier would be to just omit that property:

```
var mc =
    fixture.Build<MyClass>().Without(x => x.SomeWeirdText).CreateAnonymous();
```

However, once you start wanting to do this repeatedly, there are better options. AutoFixture has a very sophisticated and customizable engine for defining how things get created.

As a start, one could start by moving the omission of the property into a customization, like this:

```
fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.Without(x => x.SomeWeirdText));
```

Now, whenever the fixture creates an instance of MyClass, it's just going to skip that property altogether. You can still assign a value afterwards:

```
var mc = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyClass>();
my.SomeWeirdText = "bar";
```

If you want something more sophisticated, you can [implement a custom ISpecimenBuilder](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/19/ConventionbasedCustomizationsWithAutoFixture.aspx). If you want to run some custom code after the instance has been created, you can decorate your own ISpecimenBuilder with a Postprocessor and supply a delegate. That might look something like this:

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new Postprocessor(yourCustomSpecimenBuilder, obj =>
        { */ do something to obj here */ }));
```

(BTW, are you still on AutoFixture 1.0? IIRC, there hasn't been an `ObjectBuilder<T>` around since then...)

Comment: Adding a postprocessor might be just the ticket, and I appreciate the advice on proper AF usage.  Thank you!  (Regarding v1.0, yes: we had some [trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650424/autofixture-2-with-isnt-working-as-it-did-in-autofixture-1) [upgrading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595498/why-isnt-autofixture-working-with-the-stringlength-data-annotation) - maybe the third time will be the charm!)

Answer (score 3):

There's a [useful discussion on this topic on the AutoFixture CodePlex site](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/discussions/222358).

I believe my [postprocessor Customization](https://gist.github.com/3151233) linked over there should help you. Example usage:

```
class AutoControllerDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{  
    public AutoControllerDataAttribute()
        : this( new Fixture() )
    {
    }

    public AutoControllerDataAttribute( IFixture fixture )
        : base( fixture )
    {
        fixture.Customize( new AutoMoqCustomization() );
        fixture.Customize( new ApplyControllerContextCustomization() );
    }

    class ApplyControllerContextCustomization : PostProcessWhereIsACustomization<Controller>
    {
        public ApplyControllerContextCustomization()
            : base( PostProcess )
        {
        }

        static void PostProcess( Controller controller )
        {
            controller.FakeControllerContext();
            // etc. - add stuff you want to happen after the instance has been created
```