# How to use AutoFixture to generate data for a property that is a class?

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture

I'm trying to customize the data that is generated in a class .. where a property is *another* class.

eg.

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public Baa Baa { get; set; }
}


public class Baa
{
   // 30 properties which are strings, ints, etc.
}
```

I was wondering if i could do something like this...

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
return fixture.Build<Foo>()
    .With(x => x.Id, $"Foo-{fixture.Create<int>()}")
    .With(x => x.Baa, CreateSomeCustomBaaUsingAutofixture)
    .Create();
```

and then ..

```
private Baa CreateSomeCustomBaaUsingAutofixture()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    return fixture.Build<Baa>()
        .With(lots of customizations here)
    .Create();
}
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this? Or is .. that basically the only/recommended way?

I understand that AutoFixture can automatically create an instance of a `Baa` for me and data for the properties in there. I was just hoping to just customize it a bit more.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27815288/126014

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5398653/126014

Comment: Do you need `Baa` to be customized by convention, or do you need to configure it differently for each test case?

Comment: customized by convention. (so tests can reuse that same logic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to configure `Baa` by convention, you can simply do that. It might look like this:

```
fixture.Customize<Baa>(c => c
    .With(x => x.Baz, "Corge")
    .With(x => x.Qux, "Garply"));
```

Whenever you create a `Foo` object, the `Baa` property will have a value created according to those rules:

```
var foo = fixture.Create<Foo>();
Console.WriteLine(foo.Baa.Baz);
Console.WriteLine(foo.Baa.Qux);
```

Prints:

```
Corge
Garply
```

Comment: How does the `fixture.Create<Foo>();` know about how to create the `Baa`? is it because it's the same fixture instance AND the `fixture.Customize<Baa>....` comes first... Can you update the code to highlight that? (if that's what you mean) ? plz sir?

Comment: Kewl - I think i get it now. I made this .NET fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MqneEZ ... So i create the fixture, define my customizations ... then do the `Create` at the end?

Comment: @Pure.Krome That's correct. Bonus info: if you do a lot of this, you should [encapsulate your customizations](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/18/EncapsulatingAutoFixtureCustomizations).